# MATRIX Creator : Getting microphone input into pulseaudio?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, audio, pulseaudio, matrix-creator

A note on versions;
PulseAudio 10.0
Raspbian - upgraded only (not dist-upgrade) to stretch to get Pulse Audio 10

**ALSA reports the following virtual PCM interfaces; mic_channelX is the Matrix microphone array.**

```
arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sc
mic_channel0
mic_channel1
mic_channel2
mic_channel3
mic_channel4
mic_channel5
mic_channel6
mic_channel7
mic_channel8
```

**This works great from ALSA record, wav file is record of audio in the environment;**

```
arecord --device=mic_channel8 -r 16000 -c 1 -f S16_LE -vv testwav2.wav
Recording WAVE 'testwav2.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
File PCM (file=/tmp/matrix_micarray_channel_8)
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 16000
  exact rate   : 16000 (16000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 8000
  period_size  : 2000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 2000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 8000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 2097152000
Slave: Hardware PCM card 1 'Dummy' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 16000
  exact rate   : 16000 (16000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 8000
  period_size  : 2000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 2000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 8000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 2097152000
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
####### +                                          | 15%
```

My problem has been getting pulseaudio to see and use the microphones.
More history on this effort;

I noticed that the -vv shows using
Slave: Hardware PCM card 1 'Dummy' device 0 subdevice 0
file=/tmp/matrix_micarray_channel_8

Note on the following commands; These various modules are loaded one at a time (not all at the same time). Each module is commented out to try another setting. Comment them all out and Pulse works.

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

**In pulseaudio these all fail with errors on the daemon starting up (pulseaudio -vv)**

```
load-module module-pipe-source /tmp/matrix_micarray_channel_8
```

E: [pulseaudio] module-pipe-source.c: Failed to parse module arguments.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-pipe-source" (argument: "/tmp/matrix_micarray_channel_8"): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.

**_load-module module-alsa-source device=mic_channel0_**
pulseaudio: pcm_file.c:397: snd_pcm_file_add_frames: Assertion `file->wbuf_used_bytes < file->wbuf_size_bytes' failed.
Aborted

```
load-module module-alsa-source device=mic_channel8 rate=16000 channels=1 format=PA_SAMPLE_S16LE
```

*admittedly it was the "PA_SAMPLE_S16LE" that was at fault here.*

E: [pulseaudio] alsa-source.c: Failed to parse sample specification and channel map
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-source" (argument: "device=mic_channel8 rate=16000 channels=1 format=PA_SAMPLE_S16LE"): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.

**This module doesn’t complain about argument parsing, but instead fails with the assertion below.**

```
load-module module-alsa-source device=mic_channel8 rate=16000 channels=1 format=s16le
```

pulseaudio: pcm_file.c:397: snd_pcm_file_add_frames: Assertion `file->wbuf_used_bytes < file->wbuf_size_bytes' failed.
Aborted

All in all, I'm not sure where to go next with PulseAudio.

What am I over all trying to do?
  Speaker output, Microphone input routed through to BlueTooth.  All roads seem to point to pulseaudio to facilitated that.
I have speaker output working.

Comment: Were you able to make PulseAudio see and use Matrix Creator mics?

Comment: We tried many hacks around the issue. none worked.   Maybe newer drivers will work from this year.  With the audio interface being virtual in ALSA. Pulse Audio cannot touch it.

Comment: For general documentation use this : https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/raspberrypi and for setup with PulseAudio and Alsa using avahi this should work https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11124